# Uncaught syntax error: invalid token while executing javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i am trying to build dynamic input fields using javascript and codeigniter. while executing the snippet, there is an error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

i have created table where i am fetching data from database. All of my tables data is is working fine with the javascript snipped except one where i have a drop down list.

This is my table where i am fetching data.

```
<td><input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Parameter"></td>
                                         <td> <?php echo form_dropdown('id',$unit_name, '', 'class="form-control"');?> </td>
                                         <td> <input type="quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity"></td>
                                         <td><input type="price" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Enter Price"></td>
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
```

This is my javascript snippet where i am making the table dynamic to add more rows of the same input fields.

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"> <td><input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Parameter"></td>\n\
  <td> <input type="quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity"></td>\n\
  <td> <?php echo form_dropdown('id',$unit_name, '', 'class="form-control"');?> </td>\n\
<td><input type="price" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Enter Price"></td>\n\
<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      }); 


 });  



 </script>
```

My above javascript function works fine if i remove this line from the function

```
<td> <?php echo form_dropdown('id',$unit_name, '', 'class="form-control"');?> </td>\n\
```

But if i add this line i get that described error.

Comment: I have tried to remove \n\ as suggested but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<td> <?php echo form_dropdown("id",$unit_name, "", "class="form-control"");?> </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I have tried the above line of code  but it gave me following error before executing the snippet.    ```  Syntax error
 unexpected: identifier 'form'
 after: String '"class="'
 expected: instanceof, as, =>, }, ',', OR, XOR, &&, ?, ;, ||, ```